# readdir() includes an empty folder

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, gallery, opendir

I have this part of script that echos the folders in "albums" folder and arrange them by the alphabet, but for some reason it also includes an empty folder.

```
$directory = opendir("albums/");
$items = array();  
while($items[] = readdir($directory))
    sort($items);
closedir($directory);
foreach ($items as $item)
{  
    if(($item != ".") && ($item != "..")){  
        $files[] = $item;
    }
}
```

What should I do? I think the `if(($item != ".") && ($item != ".."))` is part of my problem but I can't figure how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is the current directory and `..` is the parent directory. It's normal that readdir() returns these.

BTW you could simplify your code by using the glob() function:

```
$files = glob("albums/*");
// that's all
```

[`glob("albums/*")`](http://php.net/glob) will return all entries in the albums directory, sorted alphabetically, and without the dot and dotdot entries.

Comment: and it will arrange it by the alphabet??

Comment: but whem i use it like this - <?php 
$files = glob("albums/*");
{
    foreach($files as $file)
    {

    echo $file;
 }
}
?> it returns albums/aalbums/balbums/calbums/dalbums/e (there are folders named a,b,c,d,e) and i need it return only a/b/c/d/e..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
while($items[] = readdir($directory))
```

`readdir` returns `false` if no entries are left. That is why you have an extra item in `$items`

**EDIT**

```
while($item = readdir($directory))
{
  $items[] = $item;
  sort($items);
}
```

Comment: still not working.. the folder name is "a" and it gives me 'a.php' and 'albums/a.php', and 'albums/a.php' doesn't exist and i don't need it to be exist

Comment: I think it would be faster if the `sort` is after the `while`.

Comment: @Rolando, what if a file is named `0` ? Use `while (($item = readdir($directory)) !== false)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as it's in sorted order, just array_shift() twice will do this work. But personally I think it's a kinda hacking...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$files = array();

foreach (glob('album/*') as $file) {
    if (!is_dir($file)) {
        $files[] = basename($file);
    }
}

sort($files);
```

You can modify `'album/*'` to suit your needs (ex. `'album/*.mp3'`).  Note that this method is not recursive, so if you need to process subdirectories within the album/ directory, you'll want to modify the code to account for this.